# capture all characters between match character (single or repeated) on string

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I'm trying to extract the string preceding a specific character (even when character is repeated, like this (ie: underscore '_'):

```
this_is_my_example_line_0
this_is_my_example_line_1_
this_is_my_example_line_2___
_this_is_my_ _example_line_3_
__this_is_my___example_line_4__
```

and after running my regex I should get this (the regex should ignore the any instances of the matching character in the middle of the string):

```
this_is_my_example_line_0
this_is_my_example_line_1
this_is_my_example_line_2
this_is_my_ _example_line_3
this_is_my___example_line_4
```

**In other words I'm trying to 'trim' the matched character(s) at the beginning and end of string.**

I'm trying to use a Regex in Java to accomplish this, my idea is to capture the group of characters between the special character(s) at the end or beginning of the line.

So far I can only do this successfully for example 3 with this regexp:

```
/[^_]+|_+(.*)[_$]+|_$+/

[^_]+ not 'underscore' once or more 
| OR 
_+ underscore once or more
(.*) capture all characters
[_$]+ not 'underscore' once or more followed by end of line
 |_$+ OR 'underscore' once or more followed by end of line
```

I just realized that this excludes the first word of the message on example 0,1,2 since the string doesn't start with underscore and it only starts matching after finding a underscore..

Is there an easier way not involving regex? 
I don't really care about the first character (although it would be nice) I only need to ignore the repeating character at the end.. it looks that ([by this regex tester](http://regexr.com?355f9)) just doing this, would work? `/()_+$/` the empty parenthesis matches anything before a single or repeting matches at the end of the line.. would that be correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to trim off all of the underscores from the beginning and end of the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options here, you could either replace matches of `^_+|_+$` with an empty string, or extract the contents of the first capture group from the match of `^_*(.*?)_*$`.  Note that if your strings may be multiple lines and you want to perform the replacement on each line then you will need to use the `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag for either approach.  If your strings may be multiple lines and you only want to replacement to occur at the very beginning and end, don't use `Pattern.MULTILINE` but use `Pattern.DOTALL` for the second approach.

For example: http://regexr.com?355ff

Comment: ohh the key for making the regex ^~*(.*?)~*$ work was the lazy matching in the middle! so the end part of the regex ~*$ would be able to capture the rest! :)

Answer (score 2):

How about `[^_\n\r](.*[^_\n\r])?`?

Demo

```
String data=
        "this_is_my_example_line_0\n" +
        "this_is_my_example_line_1_\n" +
        "this_is_my_example_line_2___\n" +
        "_this_is_my_ _example_line_3_\n" +
        "__this_is_my___example_line_4__";

Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[^_\n\r](.*[^_\n\r])?");
Matcher m=p.matcher(data);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

output:

```
this_is_my_example_line_0
this_is_my_example_line_1
this_is_my_example_line_2
this_is_my_ _example_line_3
this_is_my___example_line_4
```

Comment: are you using Java? mm I wonder if the regex testers that I've been trying are incorrect... because according to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ your regex omits the first character of each sentece

Comment: ohh it matches fine, but the group that they show is incorrect.. I think they are wrong http://regexr.com?355fi

Comment: @david If you want to put entire match in group one you need to surround regex with parenthesis like `([^_\n\r](.*[^_\n\r])?)`. In Java you can have entire match using group 0.

Comment: @david From what I see if you want to use entire match in at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ then you need to use `$&` instead of `$1`